# Display Driver stopped responding and has recovered

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, display

I am receiving the following error many times:

[image]

My computer has Intel HD Graphics card inbuilt into motherboard which has been updated to latest version, but I'm still receiving the same error again & again.

What should I do?

Comment: Did you update your driver before or after the error message started?    Is this a laptop?

Comment: Yes i update the driver before the error message. this is desktop that has Win 7 x86 Professional Edition.

Comment: any other inputs.?

Comment: @romilnagrani What is the computer doing when this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into the Device Manager and roll back the drivers to the previous version. If you did not use the drivers available from the motherboard manufacturer, download and use those instead of Intel's drivers which are probably not optimised for your particular motherboard configuration.

Comment: my motherboard manufacture is Intel only!.. its Intel DH55TC